# gcloud auth configure-docker fail (config.json could not be read as JSON)

Tags: docker, gcloud, google-container-registry

I tried to push my docker image onto Google container registry, but I got an Error during authenticating gcloud service on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ gcloud auth configure-docker
```

and here is the error message I got:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.configure-docker) Docker configuration file [/home
/username/.docker/config.json] could not be read as JSON: could not 
retrieve Docker client version
```

My docker version is:

```
Client:
    Version:    18.03.0-ce
    API version:    1.37
    Go version: go1.9.4
    Git commit: 0520e24
    Built:  Wed Mar 21 23:10:01 2018
    OS/Arch:    linux/amd64
    Experimental:   false
    Orchestrator:   swarm

Server:
    Engine:
    Version:    18.03.0-ce
    API version:    1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
    Go version: go1.9.4
    Git commit: 0520e24
    Built:  Wed Mar 21 23:08:31 2018
    OS/Arch:    linux/amd64
    Experimental:   false
```

I have tried other version on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ apt-cache madison docker-ce
```

These versions are cached:

```
18.03.0~ce-0~ubuntu
17.12.1~ce-0~ubuntu
17.12.0~ce-0~ubuntu
17.09.1~ce-0~ubuntu
17.09.0~ce-0~ubuntu
17.06.2~ce-0~ubuntu
17.06.1~ce-0~ubuntu ...
```

and my config.json is:

```
{
 "auths": {},
 "credHelpers": {
   "asia.gcr.io": "gcr",
   "eu.gcr.io": "gcr",
   "gcr.io": "gcr",
   "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcr",
   "us.gcr.io": "gcr"
 }
}
```

Comment: This error means that gcloud couldn't find the docker version. What happens when you run $ docker version --format '{{.Client.Version}}' ?

Comment: Hello Kristen, I tried the command **$ docker version --format '{{.Client.Version}}'** and it shows 17.06.1~ce. I also change my docker version from 17.06.1~ce-0~ubuntu to 18.03.0~ce-0~ubuntu but that doesn't work. **However I have another computer which uses docker 1.13.1 and it can push the image to the gcloud.**

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/docker-credential-gcr/issues/10.

I just follow the solution answered by beatcracker:

1. Check your docker version is bellow 18.03. This is a restriction of gcloud sdk if you want to use the command "$ gcloud docker -- push ".
2. Install virtual box to install docker-machine.
3. Install docker-machine.
4. Run command: $ docker-machine create default
5. Run command: $ eval $(docker-machine env default)
6. Run command: $ docker-credential-gcr configure-docker
7. Run command: $ gcloud auth configure-docker

then you can push docker image to gcr !

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with a similar issue in GCP Cloud Shell.
When I inspected the `/home/username/.docker` folder I found the `config.json` file to be empty.

After deleting the file and executing `$ gcloud auth configure-docker` again everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it simply meant that the docker service was not running; apparently the `~/.docker/config.json` file is only created when it is

To remediate this from the terminal: `sudo systemctl start docker.service`